# Compute digital signature using SignedCms class

Tags: .net, digital-signature

I am signing some data using the ContentInfo, SignedCms and CmsSigner classes included in .NET Framework. The signature follows the CAdES standard.

As per documentation, the CmsSigner class generates automatically the contentType and messageDigest signed attributes when at least one signed attribute is added in the CmsSigner.SignedAttributes collection. In my code I add 2 signed attributes, in this order: signing-certificate-v2 and signature-policy-identifier.

When I inspect the generated PKCS#7 object, the signed attributes appear in this order: signature-policy-identifier, contentType, messageDigest and signing-certificate-v2.

Is there a possibility to control the order of the attributes? The order I need is contentType, messageDigest, signing-certificate-v2, signature-policy-identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely not the answer you are expecting but when you'll take a look at [RFC5652](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652) you'll find out that `SignedAttributes` are defined as `SET OF` not as `SEQUENCE OF`:

```
SignedAttributes ::= SET SIZE (1..MAX) OF Attribute
```

When you'll take a look at [A Layman's Guide to a Subset of ASN.1, BER, and DER](http://luca.ntop.org/Teaching/Appunti/asn1.html) you'll see the difference between these two:

`SET OF` - an **unordered** collection of zero or more occurrences of a given type
`SEQUENCE OF` - an **ordered** collection of zero or more occurrences of a given type

So to sum it up => [RFC5652](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652) states that signed attributes in CMS structure are unordered => their order does not matter.